# Prove there exists a non-zero functional $ϕ \in V^*$ such that $f^*(ϕ) = 2ϕ$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f \in \operatorname{Hom}(V, V )$ be a linear map. Prove that if there exists a non-zero vector $w \in V$ such that $f(w) = 2w$, then there exists a non-zero functional $ϕ \in V^*$  such that $f^*(ϕ) = 2ϕ$.

Functionals really confuse me. I know they are functions in the dual space that yield a scalar. So I'm just confused as to what to do in this problem.

Comment: What does $f(\phi)$ mean?

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot a *. It still makes zero sense to me, but I hope that is clearer to everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Fix $\varphi\in V^*$, and let $\psi=f^*(\varphi)$; then $\psi\in V^*$, so $\psi$ is a linear map from $V$ to the underlying field, which I’ll assume is $\Bbb R$. Specifically, by definition $\psi(v)=\varphi\big(f(v)\big)$ for each $v\in V$. You want to choose $\varphi$ so that $\psi(v)=2\varphi(v)$ for each $v\in V$, i.e., so that $\varphi\big(f(v)\big)=2\varphi(v)$ for each $v\in V$.

Now you have $w\ne 0$ such that $f(w)=2w$, so no matter what $\varphi$ you choose, you’re going to have $\varphi\big(f(w)\big)=\varphi(2w)=2\varphi(w)$; the trick is to choose $\varphi$ to make this happen for every $v\in V$. What if you extend the set $\{w\}$ to a basis $B$ for $V$? Then you can write every $v\in V$ uniquely in the form

$$v=\sum_{b\in B}\alpha_bb\tag{1}$$

with coefficients $\alpha_b\in\Bbb R$. The map sending $v$ to the coefficient of $w$ in $(1)$ is a linear functional.